# "this kernel requires an x86-64 cpu but only detected an i686 cpu. unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your cpu"

Tags: boot, cpu

I am installing ubuntu on my real computer but with the error "this kernel requires an x86-64 cpu but only detected an i686 cpu. unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your cpu" help me!!

Comment: Your ISO isn't the correct *architecture* for your *unstated* computer.  You need to download and use an ISO that is appropriate for your machine. Your machine is likely x86 only and cannot run amd64 ISOs.  You didn't mention which OS & release you are talking about, but you'll want to use a 18.04 *flavor*.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to install latest latest Ubuntu Desktop 20.10 (or 20.04 LTS) on x86 (32bit) PC, you will fail, as they were released only as 64-bit (amd64) images.

I'm afraid you will need to use:
`ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-i386.iso`

Look for 32-bit i386 ISO here:
https://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

I'm adding link to i386 of 18.04 Ubuntu **MATE** flavour. It will offer longer support than 16.04. Unfortunately as much as I know, base Ubuntu flavor was never released as 32-bit/i386. There is also Lubuntu flavor available, maybe others exist as well (didn't look).

Dowbload page: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/18.04/release/

Look for: `ubuntu-mate-18.04.5-desktop-i386.iso`

Edit: don't ask me why download/release page says "Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (Xenial Xerus)" and download link downloads "ubuntu-16.04.6-desktop-i386.iso"...

Edit: Added i386 iso of 18.04 Ubuntu MATE

Comment: 20.10 (*groovy*) will **not** provide that message; see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1895956   Personally I'd use a 18.04 LTS *flavor* as they are lighter and perform better, and whilst the *flavors* won't have any longer life than a Ubuntu 16.04 image, the 18.04 base has two years longer of supported life.

Comment: Thanks, I've added Mate link and mentioned Lubuntu and "others" as per your suggestion.

Comment: The lightest *flavor* in my opinion is Lubuntu; second lightest is Xubuntu.  Ubuntu-MATE was good in prior releases (before the port to all GTK3), but GTK3 was noticeably slower on pentium M (x86) laptops; a little less so on pentium 4d. Xubuntu hadn't completed it's port (from GTK2 to GTK3) on 18.04 thus performed better on really old x86 boxes in my experience (Lubuntu was still all GTK2).   The best for you though is for you to decide, using GTK3 apps on a GTK2 base (eg. Lubuntu) may differ little to GTK3 apps on MATE (which is GTK3).. ie. your end-use-case will decide what's best for you.